# jQuery Validation Plugin check if "total_cost" is greater than "user_credit" value in fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am having hard time understand how jQuery Validation Plugin works with custom method.For all the guides here i found, are either for input form or static values but mine is a bit different.

I have 2 div's like 2 values and one is value of "user_credit" which store how much user have credit. And another is "total_cost" which store total cost of some special options.

The problem and difference that i have and didn't found on any guide is that my "total_cost" is dynamically changed based on previous checkbox values.

Here's part of code from that:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <label for="link_to_video">Link to video <i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add link to your product video. Youtube videos will be automatically embedded"></i></label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="show_video" id="show_video" value="1" data-price="40">
                            </span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="link_to_video" id="link_to_video" placeholder="https://youtube.com/watch?v">
                       </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <label for="link_to_product">Link to product <i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add link to your product"></i></label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="show_product" id="show_product" value="1" data-price="40">
                            </span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="link_to_product" id="link_to_video" placeholder="http://yourwebsite.com/product-page">
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h4>Your credit <span class="label label-default" id="user_credit">2000</span></h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h4>Total cost <span class="label label-default" id="total_price">0</span></h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And here is part of code that change "total_price" value when some of checkboxes are checked from above.

```
$inputs=$('#show_product,#show_video').change(function(){
    var total=0;
    $inputs.filter(':checked').each(function(){
        total+= $(this).data('price');
    });
    $("#total_price").text(total);
});
```

And another thing is that all guides activate validator in javascript while i activate in form it self

```
<form action="" name="createListingForm" id="createListingForm" method="POST" role="form" data-toggle="validator" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I have been following documentation from here https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/ and searched for alot of guides but no luck in finding solution.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you can **not** validate the text within a `span` container.  Using this plugin, you can only validate `textarea`, `select`, certain types of `input` elements, and elements with the `contenteditable` attribute... and they all **must** be within a `form` container.

Secondly, if you dynamically change the value of one of these form inputs, you simply call the `.valid()` method to programmatically trigger validation on this input.

```
$('#myinput').valid();  // trigger a validation test of #myinput element
```